# Object not callable python

Tags: python, tkinter, callable

Got this error while trying to get the variables out of a class.
Using tkinter and a class Options

```
width = ins.width()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Are you sure `width` is a *method* and not a *property*? Have you tried `ins.width`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`width` is not a method (which you can call), but an attribute (of type `int`).

If you re-read the error it might start to make more sense.

In short: you just need to drop the parentheses.

e.g.

```
width = ins.width
```

Answer (score 1):

You always have to distinguish between a called method and a simple attribute access. `width` seems to be either a property or an ordinary instance variable, not a method. Thus you can't call it but just get (or set) it's value.

```
width = ins.width
```

Answer (score 0):

the `()` is for only function/method calls in python. what you want is access to a property like `ins.width`